# Trouble connecting to laravel api with jwt while hosting on 000webhost

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt, shared-hosting

i am trying to host a project on 000webhost free tier and i am stuck on this problem. I have searched everywhere i could and still no solution. The project is a laravel 5.7 api using jwt for authentication and works fine on localhost. i uploaded everything on 000webhost without a problem and set up the database with this.

I know it is up and working to a certain degree as i can access the index.php and it shows up.(It is just a page showing 'hello' on it).

My problem is when i try to make a call to the '/api/showAuthUser' endpoint using postman I get this error.

```
Argument 3 passed to Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac::doVerify() must be an instance of Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key, null given, called in /storage/ssd1/450/8968450/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/BaseSigner.php on line 42
```

When i try to make a call to '/api/login' using postman i get this error.

```
Argument 2 passed to Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac::createHash() must be an instance of Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key, null given, called in /storage/ssd1/450/8968450/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/BaseSigner.php on line 34
```

I am sure I have the database connected correctly and I have the jwt secret in the .env file. I have tried every solution I could find online with no joy. The only one i have not tried was running `php artisan jwt:secret` as I can not run commands in 000webhost or I just don't know how to do this.

Sorry if this is not enough information but I am new to api's and this is my last hope. Thank you.

Comment: [This post may help you](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-into-000webhost-site/127323) . It shows how to step by step configure a laravel project in 000webhost

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast reply. I followed this guide and done everything plus more shown in it. It still did not work. I think my problem has something to do with the JWT but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Is there a JWT_SECRET key generated inside your local env file? Try including that JWT_SECRET and the key in env file in the hosted instance.

Comment: Yes all the keys and secrets are in the files, but i generated them on my local machine. I am unable to run commands on the server so can not re run the commands.

Answer (score 2):

You have a jwt.php file in your config folder (config/jwt.php). In there please replace the **JWT_SECRET** with your generated jwt secret key on your .env file

In **jwt.php** file

```
'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET', 'PLACE YOUR JWT KEY HERE'),
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had gave up using 000webhost as i was running out of time. I ended up using a godaddy account i had. I used the same code with the same keys and it worked fine there. The one difference when uploading to godaddy was instead of just uploading the Laravel files to the root like shown here[link](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/deploy-laravel-project-into-000webhost-site/127323) i put all the files in a folder names laravel. i then put all the files from public into public_html and changed the bootstrap paths to the laravel folder. I hope i explained it well.